# Create sandbox from Salesforce production

Tags: sandbox

We have setup Salesforce production with lead, account, opportunity and contact objects modified. Created new reports and setup users and profile.

So if I will create 2 sandboxes from this production instance, would there be any impact on production instance? Or just a new sandbox would be created with all this setup we have already done in Production instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a sandbox, Salesforce copies the metadata from your production org to a sandbox org. So, there won't be any impact on the Production instance when creating the sandboxes. 
We just need to decide the type of sandbox we need to create as per the need of data and storage.

Salesforce link that will let you know all the considerations: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&type=0

Comment: Did this help? @SanchitMittal